# What's the meaning of following ereg_replace?

Tags: php, sql, regex, sql-injection

I saw this line in a anti-sql-injection routine, so what's the meaning of it?

```
ereg_replace('(%)', '\\\1', $str);
```

Comment: Once you get a good understanding of `ereg_replace`, you should shift to `preg_replace` immediately. `ereg` functions are now obsolete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's escaping the percent sign by replacing `%` with `\%`. PHP has better ways of escaping characters, namely [`addcslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addcslashes.php):

```
addcslashes($str, '%');`
```

Also note that the ereg family of functions is deprecated in favor of their preg equivalents.

Comment: Why do we replace % with \%? The routine has already called the real_escape_string, actually it added this line of code and then called itself super_escape_string.

Comment: @Jichao Because `%` has special meaning within an SQL query (it's like a wild card for pattern matching), while `\%` is always a literal percent sign.

Comment: I agree with the parameterized statement advice.  However, [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) doesn't handle `%` (see last Note).  For prepared statements, it probably depends on the library.  I'm not saying that regex is correct, though (it's definitely overly verbose).